# How do I create a random VECTOR

Tags: python, random, vector

I'm completely new to Python, in fact the last time I knew any programming it was commodor-64 basic (apologies).

I'm trying to create random vectors in PYHON.  The vector is 52 digits bit only containing 0 - 12 and the vector itself must not repeat. I tried this...

```
from random import randint
        vector = [randint(0, 12) for p in range(0, 52)]
```

...but I suspect (although it kind of does the job), I have no way of telling if it isn't repeating the full 52 digit vector at any point. I ran it for several hours and it generated over 44 million times but didn't match the number I wanted it to...I don't even know how many permitations there would be... I'm guessing 52! (51 x 50 x 49...etc) so 44 million is a drop in the (VERY BIG) ocean (my maths isn't up to that).

Or am I wasting my time?

Thanks folks

```
from random import randint
        vector = [randint(0, 12) for p in range(0, 52)]
```

I want to repeatedly create a 52 digit vector/matrix of numbers 0 - 12 with no repeat of whole vector (simulated deck of cards shuffle) in Python.

Comment: I'm not understanding your description of the problem. If you're generating 52 independent values in the range 0 - 12, that doesn't conform to saying it's a "simulated deck of cards shuffle". You might end up with eight 5's and no 3's, for example. Why don't you start with a list containing all 52 cards (AC, 2C,...,QS, KS) and then [shuffle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) them?

Comment: Thanks for replying.  Good point well made, I guess it was a bad analogy (the card shuffle thing), that's not really my aim, it was just all I could think of to try to ecplain.  It doesn't really matter how many repeats of individual items there are. As long as the whole sequence is not repeated.  I thought about having a variable per item, then thought there mist be a better, more mathematical way (just can't figure out what). Thanks I'll experent with your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little difficult to parse, but with less than 52 values trying to fill 52 indicies, you fundamentally want more degrees than you have!

Instead of trying to make a list from random elements, you could create a collection indexing each card and shuffle or take without replacement from it!

```py
card_indicies = list(range(52))
random.shuffle(card_indicies)  # in-place single random shuffle
```

repeated way to sample the collection

```py
card_indicies = list(range(52))
random.sample(card_indicies, len(card_indicies))  # take every element
```

---

However you get your collection, packing each into a `set()` and checking if it exists will prevent duplicates

```py
card_indicies = list(range(52))
results = set()
for index_attempt in range(10000):  # tune to attempts
    results.add(
        tuple(random.sample(card_indicies, len(card_indicies)))
    )
```

---

Finally, if you just need random and independent values, you could instead have a formulaic way to determine the index in the full collection and to choose from it randomly

```py
def index_select(choices, positions):
    choices_total = choices**positions
    value = random.randrange(choices_total)
    result = []
    for _ in range(positions):
        index_value = value % choices
        result.append(index_value)
        value = value // choices
    return result
```

```py
>>> index_select(3, 4)
[2, 0, 0, 2]
>>> index_select(3, 4)
[2, 1, 1, 0]
>>> index_select(12, 52)
[6, 11, 8, 3, 2, 4, 8, 11, 4, 3, 8, 4, 5, 6, 4, 10, 9, 5, 0, 10, 7, 0, 8, 3, 9, 1, 7, 5, 6, 3, 6, 5, 8, 10, 11, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 5, 0, 9, 10, 7, 10, 8, 7, 11, 8]
```

Comment: Thanks for replying.  This looks (from your examples) like it may do the trick, however, due to my ineptitude I can't seem to get it to work.  I'll keep trying.

Comment: don't be so hard on yourself - any error may reveal itself and I mix using the interpreter in the final block, while you may be building a script! I have taken out new lines that could aid readability to help with pasting into the interpreter and reduce post size .. make sure you're running the script you expect if you are, and consider adding `print()` calls all over to aid debugging

Comment: if you're comfortable with the interpreter and your environment, check out [pdb - The Python Debugger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) to debug small programs `python3 -m pdb myscript.py` .. use `b` to set a breakpoint (so you can inspect your program there), `c` to run up to that point (continue), and `?` to explore commands .. this will allow you to inspect the live state of your program wherever you breakpoint or continue to .. this may be familiar to your Commodore 64 BASIC memories, but beware may not work nicely under Windows without WSL 2

Comment: perhaps a stretch, but these types of examples may aid you too https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Factorial#BASIC https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Factorial#Python

Comment: Wow, thanks for your help.  This ALMOST works as desired ...except, the VECTOR that is generated is with {} brackets, divided by subgroups inside () bracketz.

Comment: I need the whole vector to be within [ ] to allow me to select several "cards" to be manipulated by a further algorithm.

Comment: Thank you so much for your helpful input so far.

Comment: Well, thanks guys.  The code I wrote did what I asked of it (to a degree) but didn't come up with the redults i need...never mind eh

Comment: card_indicies = [randint (0, 9) for z in range (256)]
    random.sample(card_indicies, len(card_indicies))
    vector = (card_indicies)
    results =[]

Comment: This above (sorry, don't know how to format it),  in the end, did what I asked for.  But didn't work for what I wanted it to.  Many thanks all who helped.  I'm now gonna tey to replicate it in c# in the hope it's a little bit quicker to cross reference more codes per vector.

Comment: somewhat excellent! practically, you may find NumPy will do what you're after faster

Comment: Thanks, I've changed it to use numpy randint, and ammended the 'sample' line to sample the numpy.tolist() output.  It works and when a match is reached prints my array.  Now I'm trying to match 2x 5 digit codes...obviously it's taking forever and may still not do what I'm hoping for :(   thanks for your help.

Comment: SMH...to this day I still haven't managed to port this to c#.  It just keeps hanging :(

Comment: Can anyone please explain how to do the below python code in c# pleeeease....Ive managed to get it almost right using stringbuilder and the .Append function, but it doesn't actually do what this code does. 
The python code generates a 256 digit list of chars 0 - 9 randomly.  Then I can use this list to run an algorithm on.  I want to do this in c# because I'm hoping its much quicker.   Thanks...card_indiciess = randint (0, 10, 256)
    random.sample(card_indicies.tolist(), len(card_indicies))
    vector = (card_indicies.tolist())
    results =[]

Comment: if you have a new Question, please ask one and reference it here! speed will be highly dependent on the implementation - it's generally important to understand where time is being spent to make things faster .. at least Python has [cProfile and profile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html), and many 3rd party implementations such as the excellent [pyinstrument](https://github.com/joerick/pyinstrument)